# Using extern variables in multiple C files

Tags: c, linux, gcc, extern

Hi StackOverflow wizards:

I have the following three simple C files:

```
// File 1
#include "mainPgm.h"
void file1() {
  printf("N1 is now %d.\n", n1);                    
}

// File 2
#include "mainPgm.h"
void file2() {
  printf("N2 is now %d.\n", n2);                    
}

// File 3
#include "mainPgm.h"
void file3() {
  printf("N3 is now %d.\n", n3);                    
}
```

And, of course a main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mainPgm.h"

int main() {
  int n1 = 65536,
      n2 = 256,
      n3 = 16;

  file1();
  file2();
  file3();
}
```

Finally, a header file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void file1(), file2(), file3();
extern int n1, n2, n3;
```

All these are compiled with a simple gcc command:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -o jj -Wunused file1.c file2.c file3.c mainPgm.c
```

This results in the following errors:

```
mainPgm.c: In function ‘main’:
mainPgm.c:8:7: warning: unused variable ‘n3’ [-Wunused-variable]
mainPgm.c:7:7: warning: unused variable ‘n2’ [-Wunused-variable]
mainPgm.c:6:7: warning: unused variable ‘n1’ [-Wunused-variable]
/tmp/ccVQjFHY.o: In function `file1':
file1.c:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `n1'
/tmp/ccZqyI0n.o: In function `file2':
file2.c:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `n2'
/tmp/ccbpJOpN.o: In function `file3':
file3.c:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `n3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I *thought* that defining n1, n2, and n3 in mainPgm.h would serve to declare the variables, and their definition in mainPgm.c would define them.  No so!  Where did I go wrong?

TIA!

Comment: See [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#1433387)

Comment: You might (or might not) care to note that: (1) Your main program does not use any code from `<stdlib.h>` or `<stdio.h>` (so those includes are unnecessary); (2) The header `"mainPgm.h"` doesn't need to include `<stdio.h>` as none of the declarations in it depend on any declarations from `<stdio.h>` — but if you removed `<stdio.h>` from `"mainPgm.h"`, you'd need to explicitly include `<stdio.h>` in each of the `fileN.c` files.  In the `mainPgm.c` file, you actually included `<stdio.h>` twice.  This is harmless; standard C headers are self-contained and idempotent.  Your header should be too.

Comment: I removed the stdio and stdlib declarations from mainPgm.c, and had no compilation problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your variables are local variable inside `main()`, they will never be visible from outside that function.

Move them out so they're global:

```
  int n1 = 65536,
      n2 = 256,
      n3 = 16;

int main() {
  file1();
  file2();
  file3();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This was the heart of the problem, the program now works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You defined the variables in your main() function, on the stack.

You could define them in the same file but outside of your main function.

Alternatively a common c idiom is to use the preprocessor to declare the variables as extern in all but one instance of your header file.